# Handle 404 Error without dumping the default error in log.

Tags: javascript

i'm detecting if an image exists and then handling the response differently, however as soon as I send the HTTP Request and the image doesn't exist I still get the default 404 error come up in the console. As follows:

[image]

I'm checking for 2 images, one exists and the other doesn't as you can see by the true and false, how can I stop the one above?

I tried catching the error and simply displaying nothing, but it still appears.

Code:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', this, false);
http.send();
return http.status !== 404;
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is async... You are suppose to have a callback...

Comment: @Rayon — No, it isn't. Look at the third argument to `open`. (Which is deprecated behaviour).

Comment: @Rayon I thought that, but it seems to work :S

Comment: @Quentin it's deprecated? So I shouldn't be using this right?

Comment: @Quentin - I missed that, OP is setting `async` as `false`..

Comment: @MartynBall — Correct.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to programmatically suppress the "XHR resulted in a 404 Error" message in the Developer Tools console.

Comment: Is there a way to check if an image exists without it being async as I don't really want to use a callback, I would prefer for the script to wait for the check to complete.

Answer (score 0):

you can **rewrite 404** and **check parameters to a default image**, and XHR throws default image. you can **rewrite in your rules**.

edited1
The only server-side can rewrite URL.